# Evaluating $I(A, n) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{A +\cos^n(\theta)} d\theta$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

We want to evaluate the complex-valued integral
$$I(A, n) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{A +\cos^n(\theta)} \mathrm d\theta$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ and $A \in \mathbb{C}$.

For which $A \in \mathbb{C}$ the integral exists?

For $A = 1$ the integral exists?
I'm not sure for which other $A \in \mathbb{C}$ the integral exists

Comment: Does the integral really exist for $A=1$?

Comment: I know that $I(A, n) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{1 +cos^2(\theta)} d\theta$ exists so I guess it does for $I(A, n) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{1 +cos^n(\theta)} d\theta$ as well?

Comment: Think about what happens when $\cos{\theta}=-1$ i.e when $\theta=\pi$ taking account of the parity of $n$…

Comment: If $A = 1$ and $cos(\theta) = -1$ then $I(A, n) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{0} d\theta$ which can't happen, right?

Comment: Please avoid subject lines that consist only of MathJax; it messes up some navigation shortcuts.

Comment: @user1052623 That doesn't make any sense. The cosine is only $-1$ for $\theta=\pi$ (in this interval) and it is conceivable that the integral still exists (in Lebesgue sense). Consider $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$ exists even though "$1/0$ can't happen" when $x=0$

Comment: So for which $A \in \mathbb{C}$ the integral exists?

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases: $n$ could be even or odd.

If $n$ is even, then $\{ \cos^n \theta | \theta \in [0; 2 \pi]\} = [0;1]$
hence the integral surely exists for all $A \in \Bbb C \setminus [-1;0]$.

If $A \in [-1;0]$, then only real numbers are involved (no need of complex numbers). The integrand function has a pole at some $\theta$ (such that $A + \cos^n \theta=0$), and so the integral is divergent.

Similarly, if $n$ is odd, then $\{ \cos^n \theta | \theta \in [0; 2 \pi]\} = [-1;1]$
hence the integral surely exists for all $A \in \Bbb C \setminus [-1;1]$.

Again, if $A \in [-1;1]$ you don't need complex numbers, and the integral is again divergent.